# Twitter Rest API call lookup.json always gives a code 17 error

Tags: json, api, rest, twitter

This call:

```
curl --get \
     --silent 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=124687887&include_entities=false' \
     --header 'Authorization: OAuth
                 oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxx", 
                 oauth_nonce="xxxxxxxxxx",
                 oauth_signature="xxxxxxxxxxx", 
                 oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
                 oauth_timestamp="1429869142",
                 oauth_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                 oauth_version="1.0"`
```

systematically returns:

```
{"errors":
  [{
    "code": 17,
    "message": "No user matches for specified terms."
  }]
}
```

This used to worked just fine for weeks. I had to modify a bit my tool, and made a mistake that made my tool calling this API call too often (regarding rates). Since then I'm stuck with this error, while all other API calls continue to work.

Comment: Even with your own id or your friends list ids? If that's the case I would suggest you to submit a support ticket to Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is nothing wrong with your call. The problem seems to be that the user_id you are looking for is removed from twitter.

I made a call with a client that was successful for all other ids except that one.

Did you try your call with a user_id that you know it exists.
For example try Gap twitter handle here's their user_id 18462157

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might made a mistake here

```
user_id=124687887
```

Because, the error clearly says,

> ```
> "message": "No user matches for specified terms."
> ```

Try replacing `screen_name` in the place of `124687887`.